# How to unit test pseudo elements?

Tags: unit-testing, pseudo-element, karma-jasmine

I've been asked to unit test that CSS is applied properly to my element.

However the CSS refers to pseudo element and as far as I know since they are not part of the dom, there's no access in JavaScript and so I cannot test them.

If it was a system test - I could do a css regression test with resemblejs however I require a unit test implementation.

How can I implement this with karma+jasmine+angular combo?

Answer (score 3):

David Walsh has a great answer for this—use

`window.getComputedStyle( domElement, ':before' ).getPropertyValue( propertyName );`

https://davidwalsh.name/pseudo-element